# What is the negative form of 'host-specific'?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the negative form of 'host-specific'for the following context:

Five additional host genera for *C. beticola* *(Apium, Chrysanthemum, Limonium, Malva, Spinacia)*. They are not host specific.

Comment: I’m thinking that you’ve already negated it perfectly well, and that anything else would be less clear and less concise.

Comment: Google has 203,000 results for "non-host-specific," among which 9,100 in Books, which was my instinctive guess.   https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22non-host-specific%22+

Comment: @tchrist No. There's no negated adjective there.

Comment: Although it's a corruption of the term, it's not uncommon to hear 'agnostic' in this context. So, 'host-agnostic' might imply that the host is not important or relevant.

Comment: The first example sentence no verb. Should have _are_ before the list, and no parentheses. Then you have to clear up what _they_ refers to -- C. beticola individuals, which I believe is what's intended -- or the five host genera, which makes no sense, since they're the hosts, not the parasites, and it's the parasites that may be "host-specific". Better to avoid the problem by repeating  the parasite species name: _C. beticola is not host specific._

Comment: @Jim Mack: I've heard that usage fairly often over the years. But a [quick check on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Chost+agnostic%E2%80%9D&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) suggests it's exclusive to the IT context (where the "host" is the OS/hardware platform within which an application or subroutine might be executed). That must be where I picked it up from.

Comment: If host specific is an adjective -- and it is -- than how in the world is it NOT already being negated in your example sentence?  Have you not unreinvented some nonunrenegating sense for NOT?

Answer (score 1):

From [*Birds of Prey: Health and Disease*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n4sXQbXYPOAC&pg=PA219&dq=%22host-specific%22%20generalist&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yWshVP7FF4He7AbS5IHwCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22host-specific%22%20generalist&f=false) (2008, ed. John E. Coope)...

> *It is also useful to distinguish specialist (**host-specific**) parasites from **generalists**, which can have more than one definitive host species*

Answer (score 0):

It is not one word, but you could say, "These parasites have a *broad host spectrum*." or "These parasites have a *broad host range*."

Both of these are accepted phrases in the world of parasitology:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parasite+%22broad+host+spectrum%22

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parasite%20%22broad%20host%20range%22

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like "host-indifferent". But I don't know if that's really a technical term in your literature or not. You probably ask another specialist in the field and should go with the established usage.